# Complex image to SVG Tiny without image tag

Tags: svg

To fulfill the BIMI requirements I need to create an SVG Tiny file. I made my logo in Photoshop with different layers. Whatever I try to copy them in Illustrator it is always copied as an image. If I want to export the SVG file it will always contain an image tag.

How can I get a complex logo as SVG without an image tag?

Comment: photoshop usually generates pixel based graphics (except some elements like clip paths, smart objects etc. ) **Better create your logo in AI** instead – you could try to trace/vectorize your image in illustrator. However the results are usually not great

Comment: So you mean I have to completely rebuild my logo in Illustrator?

Comment: if your logo .psd still contains e.g text layers you could try to save it as  pdf – this will at least retain most vector content. Then open it in AI once again. If your logo contains a lot of pixel based (or flattened) graphics ... you need to rebuild them. In other words: Logo designs should rather be created in vector graphic apps like Illustrator.